How to add 30 ms delay after 3.3 VDC rail is ON?
What's the simplest method to add a precision 40 ms delay to a 3.3 V rail?

22/07/2024 update:
Thanks all who contributed. For prototyping, this is what I'll have:

Device is TPS3808G33. At startup, datasheet shows RESET line is asserted (eg at 0V). After delay, RESET line goes high then turns Q2 on to  provide 3.3VDC to load B.
Capacitor Ct of 5.1nF should provide close to 30ms delay.
30/7/2024 update: decided to do prototyping with a proper sequencing chip:

C4 should provide a delay close to 30ms.

It depends what loads A and B are, and from where the 3.3V supply comes from, and why the delay is needed. And what level of 3.3V input and what level of 3.3V output defines the 40ms 1%, as these are not square waves but supply voltages with maybe few ms of linear or exponential waveform. There is no way to think a simplest method without defining the problem better.

I've used one shots. But I didn't need 1% precision (or accuracy.)

if loadA is an mcu, it can turn on loadB. If loadB is an MCU, a capacitor on it's rst/enb pin can delay boot.

How precise, really 1%?? I guess you would get 10%ish with RC and a PMOS.

So, it looks like the OP retracted the silly1% requirement for power sequencing, but still leaves the "precision" in the text body. Next step will be to edit the word "precision" out. What it would be?

What you're looking for is called power rail sequencing. There are DC/DC converters that have this already built in.
If you already have your PMIC you can use a voltage superviser which in turn can control a MOSFET to switcht the power on. Just select one with the right delay or with a settable delay.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Otherwise use a PMIC with puilt in power sequencing capabilities.

thanks! spent 4 hours, couldn't find a suitable voltage supervisor with programmable or settable delay.

Maybe something like that? https://www.ti.com/product/de-de/TPS3842

Maybe you can explain how would your solution maintain 40ms +-1% accurate delay.

thanks! proposed solution for prototype shown above.

I am not sure where the 1% accuracy comes from, power rails do have some ramp time, especially if the load contains a lot of capacitance. So you need to pay attention to voltage levels at which you are going to define the delay.
But obviously you will need a high-side power switch for the second load. And the easiest way to make a 1% accurate control circuit is to use a smallest-possible CPLD programmed for a time-out counter, like Xilnix CoolRunner or older, or similar.

This one is from eBay for $4.
The CPLD should have a quartz-crystal-based clock to meet your 1% requirement.

thanks! proposed solution for prototype shown above.

You can try LM393 connected as schmitt trigger with small hysteresis to avoid glitches on its output if 3v3 rail raises noisy after power-on.
Make R variable with trimmer to set precise 40ms.
The most left 1k resistor discharges the C after power-off. You can remove this 1k if two 10k + 6k8 ensure sufficient discharge time of C.

Or similar with transistors:
(The two npn-s should come from the same batch so they have very similar parameters).


thanks! proposed solution for prototype shown above.
